# PWX-00001 Error opening repository "dtlmsg.txt". RCs = 268/150/2

Tags: unix, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

I've been trying to get the status of Informatica CDC logger and listener via remote server, while passing the command the following error is encountered.

```
/erppwrb1/custom/cdc/PWXCDC/pwxcmd: error while loading shared libraries: libdtlinfod.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

TO fix this I tried to export library path before capturing the status but this time different error pops up.

code used to get logger status:

```
ssh cdcpwrb1@erppwabc.pw.abc.com 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/erppwrb1/oracle/11.2.0/lib:/erppwabc/custom/cdc/PWXCDC:/usr/lib;/erppwabc/custom/cdc/PWXCDC/pwxcmd displaystatus -sv ERPABC_LOGGER'

error received : "PWX-00001 Error opening repository "dtlmsg.txt". RCs = 268/150/2."
```

But when running the command

```
/erppwabc/custom/cdc/PWXCDC/pwxcmd displaystatus -sv ERPABC_LOGGER
```

directly in CDC server it fetches the status

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to export PWX_HOME as well, where the file dtlmsg.txt is present